# Set Current Date as Selected in Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using [bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) in my code. How Do I select current date in JavaScript and show it as selected?

After research this is code I am using but current day does not appear as selected:

```
var today = moment();

datepicker1.datepicker({
    endDate: today.toDate()
}); 

datepicker2.datepicker({
    startDate: today .toDate(),
    endDate: today.toDate()
});

datepicker1.datepicker('setDate', today.toDate());
datepicker2.datepicker('setDate', today.toDate());

datepicker1.datepicker('update');  //update the bootstrap datepicker
datepicker2.datepicker('update');
```

Comment: Maybe i miss something but: `startDate: new Date()`???  But wait, by default it is selecting current date so i'm really not sure to understand what is your issue?!

Comment: 1. Date does not appear in date Input field
2. Date is not selected-highlited inside date picker

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No idea about the code you are using and without HTML markup doesn't make much sense,

Here is a working example of what you are after

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var today = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
  var end = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());

  $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
todayHighlight: true,
startDate: today,
endDate: end,
autoclose: true
  });
  $('#datepicker2').datepicker({
format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
todayHighlight: true,
startDate: today,
endDate: end,
autoclose: true
  });

  $('#datepicker1,#datepicker2').datepicker('setDate', today);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2">
<div class="panel">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="datepicker1">Date</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker1">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="datepicker2">Date2</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker2">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 23):

Im using bootstrap datepicker. below code worked for me:

```
$('#my-datepicker').datepicker('setDate', 'now');
```

Comment: this is working, thank you!!

Comment: Confirmed this is working and simple to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in selecting currentdate when using `minDate : moment()`.
The solution is to use below code for assigning datetimepicker:

```
$('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker({ 
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY', 
    minDate: moment().millisecond(0).second(0).minute(0).hour(0),
    clear : false 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
$("#order_date").datepicker( {
   autoclose: true,
});

var orderDate = '2021-03-05';
$('#order_date').datepicker('update', new Date(Date.parse(orderDate)));
```

[Reference](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var today = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
  var end = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());

  $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
todayHighlight: true,
startDate: today,
endDate: end,
autoclose: true
  });
  $('#datepicker2').datepicker({
format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
todayHighlight: true,
startDate: today,
endDate: end,
autoclose: true
  });

  $('#datepicker1,#datepicker2').datepicker('setDate', today);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2">
<div class="panel">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="datepicker1">Date</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker1">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="datepicker2">Date2</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker2">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

With this you can highlight current date!

```js
$('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker({ 
  todayHighlight:true
})
```