# how can i set a default value for date in jQuery filter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using a JQuery to show a table out of a database which I am filtering with the `datetimepicker`.

What I am trying is to set a default value for my filter as the current day. 
So as default it should only show me data from the current day.

I already tried a lot and searched for many questions here, but it didn't really help me.

I tried to set it with JS as defaultDate and tried to set it after initialization with a variable.

At the moment it loads all the data out of the database, which takes a bit, so I want to change it to this way.

[image: my filters]

HTML

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datepicker1' style="width: 220px;">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        nach Datum
    </span>
    <input type='text' id="filterdatum" name="datum" value="{FILTERDATUMDEUTSCH}" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {    

$('#datetimepickerzeit').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'de',
    format: 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss'
});
// Datum filtern
$('#datepicker1').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'de',
    format: 'D.M.YYYY'
});
$('#datepicker1').on('dp.show', function () {
    $('#datepicker1').on('dp.change', function () {
        window.location = "?module=ausschuss&action=showtable&filterdate=" + $('#datepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").date().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    });
});
```

Comment: Which jquery datetimepicker plugin are you using?

Comment: I'm sorry it is the Bootstrap Datetimepicker

Comment: When we click on the "nach Datum" the filter should be applied by current date - Is it correct?

Comment: When we click on nach Datum we can choose a date, but i want that it should be chosen on today when i open the "page".

Comment: Refer the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948544/set-current-date-as-selected-in-bootstrap-datepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things I'd try. First, make sure you have a link to jQuery above your script block. Use either Google's or a local copy:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If that doesn't work, next try replacing all instances of $ in your Javascript code with jQuery:

```
jQuery(function(){ 
 jQuery('#id1').daterangepicker({
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    arrows:true,
    onChange: function(){
       jQuery('#frmDate').submit()
    },
 });
});
```

you can also try defaultDate: new Date(), in your code.